# Error in .oci.WriteTable of ROracle package

Tags: r, roracle

I have found the error using '*dbWriteTable*' and can not find any clue what way to handle it. The error is alike:

> Error in .oci.WriteTable(conn, name, value, row.names = row.names, overwrite = overwrite,  :
>
> > Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt, data = value) : 
> >       ORA-00913: too many values

I have got the Oracle table of such a structure (the extract from Oracle script):

```
create table My_table
(
 card_id    NUMBER(4),
 predictor  VARCHAR2(1000),
 interval   NUMBER(4),
 attributes VARCHAR2(1000),
 scoring    NUMBER(20,10),
 comments   VARCHAR2(1000),
 uploaded   DATE
)
```

The dataframe  contains only one row and the structure of it as follows (the R outpur of 'str' function - str(x)):

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  7 variables:  
 $ CARD_ID   : int 36  
 $ PREDICTOR : chr "YEAR"  
 $ INTERVAL  : int 1  
 $ ATTRIBUTES: chr ">= 1945 < 1960"  
 $ SCORING   : int 7000  
 $ COMMENTS  : chr "no comments"  
 $ UPLOADED  : Date, format: "2016-09-26"
```

The script to establish connection is as follows:

```
drv <- dbDriver("Oracle")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user, password, DB_name,bulk_read = rows_at_time)
```

The script to insert the dataframe into the Oracle table is as follows:

```
dbWriteTable(con, Oracle_table,  My_dataframe, row.names = FALSE, overwrite =   FALSE,
         append = TRUE, ora.number = TRUE, schema = NULL, date = FALSE
)
```

So only **dbWriteTable** generate the following error:

> Error in .oci.GetQuery(con, stmt, data = value) : ORA-00913: too many values

The structure of the tables is similar to the dataframe one. The usage with other dataset and other Oracle table seems to be ok but not with this dataframe. 
I would be glad to hear any hits how to handle this error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have found the solution to this error.
I have used **dbGetQuery(con, script,Oracle_table)**. It have worked fine. The script used as follows:

> script <- paste("insert into ", user_card_table," values (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7)")

But I wonder why there were an error in **dbWriteTable** because another script with the similar function had worked fine.